# how to show wfs and wms sources in boundlessgeo gxp viewer

Tags: maps, geoserver, wms

I'm using  [boundlessgeo gxp viewer](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp). I have a lot of different wms and wfs link and want to show those remote sources in my map viewer application. I have a geoserver and basic layers in it. I can add my local sources normally. What is the way of adding external wms and wfs sources?

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to GeoServer admin.
2. Go to Stores > Add new Store

Now, under *'Vector Data Sources'* you can select *'Web Feature Server'* and under *'Other Data Sources'* you can select *'WMS - Cascades a remote Web Map Service'*

Comment: I know Wms cascading in geoserver but I can not make cascading just about 1500 wms server. I'm using proxy for getting capabilities documents now.

Comment: OK. I focused on the last part of you question since you tagged it geoserver. 
Then your question is not about GeoServer but boundlessgeo gxp viewer. Try changing the tags to reflect that: add the boundlessgeo tag.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not add the boundlessgeo tag .

Comment: Perhaps you can close/delete this question and reformulate a bit so that it is clear that you mean adding a catalog of 1500 WMS servers to the gxp viewer. And add the boundlessgeo tag :)

Comment: New tag creation requires at least 1500 reputation :)

Comment: So, the boundless tag conforms to opengeo-suite as it seems on gis.stackexchange. Make your new question there like your last one, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119083/how-to-show-wfs-and-wms-sources-in-boundlessgeo-gxp-viewer